# How to avoid f strings and string concatenation in psycopg2 using psycopg2.sql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following query in psycopg2:

```
def insert_pairs(dat, no_transform_cols):
   # dat is a pandas dataframe containing the data, it has lots of columns 
   no_transform_cols = list(no_transform_cols) # columns in dat which can just be inserted as is
    
    cols2 = no_transform_cols + ['foo_id']                            
    cols = tuple(list(dat.columns)) # same as cols 2 except it contains column a which we use later to get the foo_id
    tuples = [tuple(x) for x in dat.to_numpy()] # convert the dataframe to tuples for insert
    
    ntc = ', '.join(['ins.' + x for x in no_transform_cols])
    cols = ', '.join(cols)
    cols2 = ', '.join(cols2)
    # SQL query to execute
    query = (f'WITH ins ({cols}) AS'
             ' (VALUES %s)'
              ' INSERT INTO bar'
                f' ({cols2})'
              ' SELECT'
                f' {ntc}'
                ' , foo.id'
              ' FROM'
                ' ins'
                ' LEFT JOIN foo ON foo.a=ins.a'
              ';')
    .
    .
    .
```

I have been trying to write this query in a way where I don't use f-strings but I have not been able to do so thus far. My understanding is that  I should use psycopg2.sql https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html to do this. But with my current skills I have so far not been able to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See the `.format` method. Right under the "Module Usage" header in the doc link you provided

Comment: I've been trying to get that to work but I don't manage to do it, especially with the `ntc` bit.